# How Skype Click to Call plugin is used to send spam?

Tags: malware, spam, skype, plugins

My friend had *Skype Click to Call* plugin installed within browser on Mac OSX.

And his Skype account started to send some automatic spam messages linking to lose weight websites (via `goo.gl`) without having actual virus/malware installed on his computer. I believe this was done via Skype Message API.

How this was exactly achieved (from JS script?) and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I don't think this is the case, and it's more likely caused by malware that was already on the system.